# Java CLASSPATH Not working?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am trying to use other jars for a program I am writing.

I installed all the required files and added them to CLASSPATH, but Java doesn't recognize the packages.

I put semicolons in between the jar locations but Java doesn't recognize the packages from the jar. Why does that happen?

For example, 
my classpath looks like:

> .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Users\JOE\Downloads\easymock-3.2\easymock-3.2\easymock-3.2.jar;C:\Users\JOE\Downloads\cglib-3.1.jar;C:\Users\JOE\Downloads\objenesis-2.1-bin\objenesis-2.1.jar

but if I try to import package `org.easymock.EasyMock` for example, the package is not recognized.

Comment: Have you checked whether the class `org.easymock.EasyMock` exists inside `easymock-3.2\easymock-3.2.jar` or not ?

Comment: You should not be using `CLASSPATH` any more. Provide the libraries through the `-cp` parameter when starting your Java application.

Comment: I was changing the environment variable CLASSPATH. What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to load dependencies from external jars, specify the paths using -classpath (or) -cp command line argument. It's not ideal to change the CLASSPATH environment variable for each and every program that you execute.

The default ClassPath for java program is dot (.) which means current directory

Remember that when you're using -cp/-classpath arguments, they'll override the default classpath settings, so you should explicitly add the default path as well like below.

On Windows

> javac -cp pathToYourJar Main.java

while executing don't forget to add your current directory

> java -cp .;pathToYourJar Main

To make things easier, I'd recommend to use an IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans/IntellijIDEA.
If your already using Eclipse, add the jars to your Project's  Build Path

Right Click on Project -- Properties -- Java Build Path -- Libraries -- Add External JARs

Comment: I'm writing this comment after trying this but it didn't work. I've a project named Helloworld which consist only 1 java file, `Helloworld/src/com/firstpackage/Test.java` (windows 10. intellij idea). I **don't** have CLASSPATH environmental variable, i want to set classpath specifically for this project. running `java com.firstpackage.Test` inside Helloworld directory doesn't work and neither does the command `java -classpath C:\Users\matuagkeetarp\IdeaProjects\Helloworld\src\com\firstpackage Test.java` set classpath variable. Can you help?